# Cannot read property 'length' of null when using MatPaginator

Tags: angular-material

I keep on getting this error:

```
core.js:1542 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at MatTableDataSource.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/table.es5.js.MatTableDataSource._filterData (table.es5.js:702)
at MapSubscriber.project (table.es5.js:657)
at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
at CombineLatestSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/observable/combineLatest.js.CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (combineLatest.js:83)
at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/BehaviorSubject.js.BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:22)
at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:89)
```

I get my data from a service that gets from a database. It functions just fine. What I mean is the functionality is right. I can do the paging it's just that I get this error in the inspector. Please see my code below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.genParams.buildingId === null || this.genParams.buildingId === undefined) {
      this.router.navigate(['/main/viewproperties']);
    }

    this.buildingId = this.genParams.buildingId;
    this.getUnits();
  }

 public getUnits() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.unitService.newGetUnits(this.buildingId)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.ELEMENT_DATA = data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

This is in my html:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[1, 5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you go to stackblitz.com and copy here a working sample so I can look further in your code? I might have a slight idea why this happens but sample is better.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is a scope issue.  Try adding this to the class, not a function.  You refer to this.datasource but setting it up as new in the function so I assume you just declare the var in the class.  I've seen this error many times and it is when my dataSource is not receiving data but you seem to indicate that your table is functioning with data.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries)

```
//  For data table operations.
  private dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  private dataLength: number;
```